# Método dentro de NLTK em python que retorna uma árvore sintática

Tags: python, parser

Estou usando a bibloteca Floresta do NLTK e vi lá que tem umas sentenças com parse(árvore sintática) já criados. Porém, eu gostaria de um método que a partir de uma nova frase ele cria o parse em português.

Exemplos:
Uso hoje

```
floresta.parsed_sents()
```

e ele me traz uma árvore montada pra cada sentença dentro do corpus existente. Eu gostaria de passar novas sentenças em português e alguma(s) função(ões) python me devolver(em) a sentença com o parse igual a função acima devolve.

Comment: Eu escrevi recentemente um posto com um exemplo de como usar a SyntaxNet (do Google), treinado para Português, para extrair uma árvore sintáctica de uma frase, e usar essa informação com as estruturas do NLTK: http://davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/03/25/syntaxnet/

Answer (score 2):

Não sei quanto ao "em português" - ou mesmo em qualquer outra linguagem natural, como o inglês - mas pelo que eu entendi o `parsed_sents` retorna uma lista de frases já "parseadas", sem especificar *como* foi feita essa análise (automaticamente ou manualmente, para servir de exemplos). Para fazer a análise de uma frase nova, é necessário usar uma gramática, e então usar o método `parse` dessa gramática. Exemplo:

```
grammar1 = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
  S -> NP VP
  VP -> V NP | V NP PP
  PP -> P NP
  V -> "saw" | "ate" | "walked"
  NP -> "John" | "Mary" | "Bob" | Det N | Det N PP
  Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
  N -> "man" | "dog" | "cat" | "telescope" | "park"
  P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
  """)
```

Essa é uma gramática simples, com poucas regras e um vocabulário restrito. Ela pode ser usada assim:

```
>>> sent = "Mary saw Bob".split()
>>> rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar1)
>>> for tree in rd_parser.parse(sent):
...      print(tree)
(S (NP Mary) (VP (V saw) (NP Bob)))
```

<sup>[Fonte](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html)</sup>

O `for` é devido à possibilidade de existirem duas ou mais interpretações para a frase, caso ela seja ambígua. Outro exemplo (só de uso, pra gramática correspondente, ver link acima):

```
>>> pdp = nltk.ProjectiveDependencyParser(groucho_dep_grammar)
>>> sent = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas'.split()
>>> trees = pdp.parse(sent)
>>> for tree in trees:
...     print(tree)
(shot I (elephant an (in (pajamas my))))
(shot I (elephant an) (in (pajamas my)))
```

A forma de usar o código, portanto, é essa. Se existem boas gramáticas para o português que possam ser usadas em conjunto com esse código (i.e. num formato aceito por essa biblioteca), aí já não sei dizer - mesmo porque a construção de uma gramática de escopo amplo é um problema bastante difícil.

Comment: Obrigado cara!! Mas então, o floresta é um corpus em português já. Só que montar o parse não pode levar em conta o modelo treinado para inglês. Imaginei que ia ter um modelo já pronto em português que eu poderia utilizar. Vou tentar explorar essa biblioteca que vc mandou com o corpus em português.

Comment: Talvez até tenha, não sei... O que quis dizer é que montar uma gramática geral é muito difícil, e tenho dúvidas se algo assim existe mesmo em inglês. O processamento de linguagem natural, até onde eu saiba, normalmente é feito usando métodos estatísticos, não formais. Seja como for, verifique se essa biblioteca floresta possui ou não gramáticas prontas para usar com o método `parse`, do contrário receio não ter nada melhor pra sugerir.

Comment: P.S. Por favor confirma pra mim se a biblioteca que você se refere é [esta](http://www.linguateca.pt/Floresta/). Pelo que andei olhando dos [exemplos em português](http://www.nltk.org/howto/portuguese_en.html), não parece ter nada que facilite o *parse* de uma frase arbitrária, como eu já suspeitava. Posso estar enganado, espero...

Comment: Isso. Eles que fizeram o corpus do floresta e fizeram o modelo a partir do NLTK. Li o artigo deles mas não deixaram exemplos ou mostraram como conseguiram isso. Estou explorando os links dentro do site deles ainda. Vou mandar um email pra eles com essas dúvidas. Logo reporto o que consegui descobrir. Valeu!

Comment: E não é que leva em conta a gramática, mas é porque a forma de criar a árvore sintática é diferente em certas linguagens. O português é parecido com o espanhol e ambos são diferentes do inglês. Por isso, um modelo que cria o parse em inglês não pode ser usado em português. Se tiver algum método dentro do NLTK que treina um novo parse a partir de alguns dados de treinamento já seria muito bom pra mim.

Answer (score 1):

O problema das arvores em português é o fato de não ter um tagger.

Você pode tentar fazer uma comparação entre seu texto e o floresta, mas ainda assim não é garantia que eles cubram todas suas palavras.

Você pode usar também o nltk.CFG.fromstring e montar sua arvore na mão, mas se ela for muito complexa acaba caindo no problema do tagger.

Não sei o tamanho da sua necessidade em criar isso, mas se quiser contribuir com o desenvolvimento de um tagger em português.

Answer (score 1):

Eu escrevi recentemente um posto com um exemplo de como usar a SyntaxNet (do Google), treinado para Português, para extrair uma árvore sintáctica de uma frase, e usar essa informação com as estruturas do NLTK:

http://davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/03/25/syntaxnet/